# Processing paragraph using sed

Tags: sed

I want to process a paragraph using sed. I want to extract sentence with odd number of words only. and then print the words in reverse order. e.g: input is 'Hello world. hello world again.' and the output required 'again world hello'

Comment: Is sed really a requirement? A full-blown scripting language is much better suited for the purpose - try Perl, Python, or maybe awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is homework, your teacher wants you to discover sed's hold pattern.  If this is not homework, it is much less awkward to do this in e.g. Perl.  Welcome to the world of wonderful Perl one-liners:

```
perl -00 -lane 'next unless @F % 2; $, = " "; print reverse @F' yourfilenamehere
```

This only does paragraphs.  Splitting into sentences and looping over those should not be too hard to hack in.

Comment: Thank you. I know Perl very well. But this was an assignment given to me. I've solved it by using a regex to write all sentence with odd number of words to an intermediate file and then processed it to reverse the sentence. Anyway thank you for attention to this question.